# Spring AMQP Exceptions

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

It's my first question here in stackoverflow. I'm working in a project which involves Spring AMQP. For the development I found this tutorial: [Spring AMQP Example](http://www.javabeat.net/sending-and-receiving-messages-using-springs-amqp/)

When I run the ListenerContainer class, I get this exception:

1. **Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIllegalStateException: No default listener method specified: Either specify a non-null value for the 'defaultListenerMethod' property or override the 'getListenerMethodName' method.**

I've been searching the solution but I can't solve it.

If anyone can help me I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with that blog post but it's using a very old (pre-release) version of Spring AMQP; the current release version is [1.4.3](http://projects.spring.io/spring-amqp/). The blog post itself is nearly 5 years old.

You should use the project's own [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/) which references the [samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples) supported by the project.

Comment: Thanks Gary! I'll try with this samples :)